# How to close mobile menu when selecting on page anchor link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, menu

I have added some anchor links to a website (https://jamesandgemmawedding.co.uk), however, when clicking them via the mobile menu it remains open taking up half of the screen. I want the mobile menu to close when clicking the anchor link.

I have tried adding jQuery code to the custom.js file, but nothing appears to work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="main-menu-container top-mobile-nav">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-26"><a href="http://jamesandgemmawedding.co.uk#rsvp" aria-current="page">RSVP</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-27"><a href="http://jamesandgemmawedding.co.uk#ceremony" aria-current="page">Ceremony</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-28"><a href="http://jamesandgemmawedding.co.uk#accommodation" aria-current="page">Accommodation</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery from the custom.js file:

```
// RESPONSIVE MENU
    jQuery( '.dt-menu-btn' ).on( 'click', function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('toggeled');
        jQuery('.main-menu-container').toggleClass('top-mobile-nav')
    });
```

As said above, I would like the mobile menu (toggle) to close when a menu-item is clicked, however, nothing I have tried yet has worked. Can anyone please advise on a solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your anchor tags:

```
onclick="jQuery( '.dt-menu-btn' ).trigger('click')"
```

This will toggle the menu while it scrolls to the appropriate anchor.

For example, use:

```
<a href="http://jamesandgemmawedding.co.uk#accommodation" aria-current="page" onclick="jQuery( '.dt-menu-btn' ).trigger('click')">Accommodation</a>
```

If you can't edit the HTML, you can bind the "click" via jQuery.

```
jQuery('#primary-menu a').on('click', function() {
    jQuery( '.dt-menu-btn' ).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The navigation uses the menu in WordPress so I’m not sure how the onclick= could be added?

Comment: @charlieg007 I edited my response to include jQuery example that you can run to attach to the click event of the links.

Comment: I have added the jQuery to the custom.js file and this doesn't appear to do anything i.e. the menu needs to close when clicking a menu item on mobile. Any ideas on why it isn't working?